# So do NPCs' on-person inventories respawn after you've pickpocketed them?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm going to try to be as specific as possible (because I saw this question: [Do the inventories of NPCs respawn with new goodies after you've pickpocketed them?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/130518/do-the-inventories-of-npcs-respawn-with-new-goodies-after-youve-pickpocketed-th)):

I am talking *only* about Skyrim and I simply want to know if NPCs respawn pickpocketed items.

I am also *not* talking about pickpocketing new NPCs that have respawned in cleared dungeons and such.  I'm just focused on the question of pickpocketing NPCs that I left alive after I robbed them and whether or not they respawn items.

I googled around and I can't get a straight answer:

- Followers never respawn
- Followers DO respawn (especially after waiting)
- Named NPCs never respawn
- The opposite of that.
- Named NPCs respawn if you leave one item on them.
- Named NPCs respawn if you take everything.
- Generic NPCs do or don't respawn, if you do or don't leave an item on them.
- Specific followers/named NPCs/generic NPCs respawn items according to hidden rules that Bethesda made up that no one can figure out.

I simply want to know which one of these statements is true.

I tried watching and it was very strange to me because early on in the game, it seemed like they never respawned items no matter how long I waited.  Later on (I had leveled up to about 30) it seemed like they DID respawn items if I waited.

Please help?  I am very confused.

Answer (score 7):

I was obsessing a little too much over this so I jettisoned my current playthrough and did a completely fresh install with *no* mods and experimented a little:

I stole everything off: generic NPCs, named NPCs, and followers both before and after I recruited them.

In all cases, if you steal everything off them, they will all respawn their clothes after 3 days.  No one goes naked forever.

Both generic *and* named (non-follower) NPCs will not respawn anything other than clothes (as far as I can tell).

I tested this on Faendal both before and after he became a follower.  Before he became a follower, he respawned clothes as well, but didn't respawn weapons.  After he became a follower and we left the cell where I made him a follower (his house), he respawned his weapons again.

This is just a preliminary answer, I'll keep updating it as I find out more.  I'd like to test it out for [up to 30 days](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Respawning), and with a few other followers.

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/how-long-does-it-take-for-pickpocketed-people-to-respawn-items.250114726/), [this link](https://steamcommunity.com/app/72850/discussions/0/535151589907554507/), and [this link](http://www.gamesas.com/any-way-making-non-respawning-npc-inventories-refresh-t256185.html) seem to imply that named NPCs do not have respawning inventories (Such as Jarl Balgruuf or Esbern), whereas generic NPCs (like bandits and guards) do reset their inventories after a long period. By stealing from a Whiterun Guard and Ysolda, stepping outside of Whiterun, waiting a week, then coming back in, my game seems to confirm this (I do have mods, although I shouldn't have any that affect this).

Assuming the above is true (EDIT: Which it doesn't seem to be, see comments), a simple answer is:

- Named NPCs never respawn (except maybe in a quest scenario where their inventory is changed)
- Followers never respawn (they are also Named NPCs)
- Generic NPCs do respawn

EDIT: Perhaps there are more checks to refresh inventories of named NPCs than I thought, or there could just be other rules in play.

Comment: Faendal will respawn his bow and i think other followers respawn their weapon as well

Comment: That's odd. Perhaps there is some hidden rule.

Comment: Sorry I took so long to reply!  I was testing it out on Skyrim and wrote up my findings.

Comment: It could be just the weapon that respawns, so that named NPCs aren't running around punching stuff.